# Insert Sort not working

Tags: c++

I am learning sorting algorithms. I googled the insert sort code and when I tried it on my own it's not working out. Can someone please find the error in my code?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,size, a[40], key;
    cout << "Enter size: ";
    cin >> size;
    for(int o=0; o<size; o++)
    {
        cin >> a[o];
    }
    //insertion sort
    for(int j = 1; j <= size-1; j++)
    {
        key = a[j];
        i = j-1;

        while((key < a[i]) && (i >= 0));
        {
          a[i + 1] = a[i];
          i = i - 1;
        }
        a[i + 1] = key;
    }
    cout << "\nSorted list is as follows\n";
    for(int o = 0; o < size; o++)
    {
        cout << endl << a[o];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem when you execute it? Describe the problem

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user the SO is not asking for a coding service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 while((key<a[i])&&(i>=0));
```

You have an infinite `while` loop here. The semi colon at the end means that the while loop body is empty. Hence `i` is never decremented and the loop runs forever.

Also, you need to check if the index is valid (`i >= 0`) before trying to access it's value.

So change the line as below.

```
 while((i >= 0) && (key < a[i]))
```